# Hippo CMS SpringBridgeHstComponent Breaks Editing Component Item Parameters

Tags: spring, hippocms

I'm currently migrating existing components to use the HST-2 Spring Bean Bridge to integrate better with the Spring IOC container.

I followed the [Hippo documentation](http://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/web-application/spring-bridge.html) and everything works as advertised, at least in the running site.  I can now define my component beans in my spring configuration and use DI for my component dependencies.

However, I learned that now I cannot modify the parameters on those component's in the Channel Manager's Template Composer.  Before migrating those catalog components to use the **SpringBridgeHstComponent** I could click in the component item area in the Template Composer and get the pop up dialog which let me view and edit all the parameters to that component item

```
(hst:parameternames, hst:parametervalues).
```

Now the pop up dialog just shows a message that

```
 "No editable properties found for this component."
```

I should mention that the component parameter values that were already set on the components are still available during request processing/execution.  But those values are now effectively "hard-coded" because the webmaster cannot view/change them in the Template Composer.

Is this a known issue with the **SpringBridgeHstComponent**?  Or is there a workaround configuration or something to make those component parameters available again in the Channel's Template Composer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Hippo CMS Channel manager can only scan annotations in the component class configured by the hst:componentclassname property.
SpringBridgeHstComponent class itself, which is used in your component
configuration now, cannot be annotated by a domain-specific parameters
info annotation. As a result, it's not shown in the channel manager
properly.

If you want to enable the parameters setting window for the
SpringBridgeHstComponent-bridged component, then you should extend the
class only for the annotation. e.g, ContactSpringBridgeHstComponent
extends SpringBridgeHstComponent with a specific annotation in that
extending class for contact component for instance. See the [docs](http://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/component-development/hstcomponent-parametersinfo-annotation.html) for detail.

This is needed at the moment because channel manager recognizes the
parameters information only by class annotation, which makes you extend
a new class for each component.